# Cannot create image button Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Edit:
I found a way from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HwHqa3tq70

but for me it doesn't work, this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
rw = Tk()
b1 = ttk.Button(rw, text = "click")
b1.pack()

filepath = "2.jpg"
mi = PhotoImage(file = filepath)


b1.config(image = mi, compound = RIGHT)
```

The error I get is this here:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "2.jpg": no such file or directory
>>> canv.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'img' is not defined
```

Any advice on that?

Comment: I'd recommend Tkinter for this

Comment: I did a research before asking but couldn't find any tutorial that fit my needs.

Comment: changed the question

Comment: Try the absolute path of 2.jpg

Comment: @FrostFire 
If you have another question create another post, do not change the question, read [ask]

Comment: The error you post could not have come from the code in your question. There is no `img` in your code, nor any call to `canv.create_image`.

Answer (score 0):

okay..you changed the question. I leave my answer to your previous question. I Hope its helpful.

You can use PyQt5.
I've a folder with this:

```
|-Project/
|--- images/
|----- 1.png
|------2.png
|--- app.py
```

There are two buttons for example "cam" icon and "user" icon:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os

class Ui_Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Example, self).__init__(parent)
        width = 350
        height = 180
        self.resize(width,height)
        self.setMaximumSize(width,height)
        self.setMinimumSize(width,height)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        self.path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),'images') #icons path

        ### icons

        usericon = QtGui.QIcon()
        usericon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(self.path, '2.png')), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)

        camicon = QtGui.QIcon()
        camicon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(self.path, '1.png')), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)

        # Button user
        self.btnuser = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btnuser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20,20,150,100))
        self.btnuser.setIcon(usericon)
        self.btnuser.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")
        self.btnuser.clicked.connect(self.ExecUserCode)
        # Button cam
        self.btncam = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btncam.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 20, 150, 100))
        self.btncam.setIcon(camicon)
        self.btncam.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")
        self.btncam.clicked.connect(self.ExecCamCode)
        # Button..
        # ...

    def ExecUserCode(self):
        print("User Code here")
    def ExecCamCode(self):
        print("Cam Code here")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = Ui_Example()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: It works very well and while tkinter didn't pyqt5 works even in Visual Studio Code. Just a Question, How can I make images a little bit bigger? and close the gui?

Comment: edit I managed how to make the icons bigger but i still don't know how to close the gui

Comment: well, you can use self.hide() to hide and execute something and finally self.show() when finish